# How to manage building a huge source code that uses gnu autotools?

Tags: build, open-source, autotools, build-tools

I have multiple source codes which I have to cross-build and use together as one huge project. The building process of each source code is the same **`'./configure-make-make install'`** commands with added parameters for cross compilation. So far I have been managing this by typing a really long configure command **`"./configure CC=....."`** in text editor and then copy pasting that on to terminal and running it. Then repeating the process for another source code. Taking care of multiple include paths, library paths, pkg-config paths etc. the process turns out to be very messy, error-prone and cumbersome. I have already used eclipse ide and have found no option for configuring the **`"./configure .."`** command to my need. Is there any elegant way to handle this problem? I would like a solution which will require me to write minimal amount of script/instruction.

Comment: How about scripting it?

Comment: @JohnBollinger that is a great solution but pretty straight-forward. I am looking for an already existing tool (preferably GUI) which will largely automate the whole process with minimal input from the user.

Comment: Requests for tool recommendations are off-topic here.  Voting to close.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I am not strictly looking for ready-made tools. I am looking for solutions. Besides various open source projects use various standards and mere 'scripting' by hand for all those projects is not productive in my opinion. The solution should be searched inside the gnu tools itself I think. Just check the answer by Vicente Adolfo Bolea Sánchez below and see what I meant.

Comment: You're being inconsistent, @Coda. First you claim to be looking for an existing tool, then you contradict yourself.  Anyway, the issue of tool recommendations aside, that leaves this question somewhere between unclear and too broad.  This is not a discussion forum.  We answer narrowly-scoped questions about programming and programming tools.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any elegant way to handle this problem?

If you want to automatize the configuration and compilation of several sub-projects which are actually one project, I suggest you to use the GNU/Autotools canonical way to deal with it with is `Nested Autotools project`

In that way you can do a project which contains all the other projects in the following fashion:

```
./UmbrellaProject
   subproject1/
   subproject2/
   ...
   Makefile.am
```

Inside the parent project `Makefile.am` you will have a line at the beginning such as:

```
 SUBDIRS = subproject1 subproject2
```

More information at the GNU Automake [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Subdirectories.html)